# IntelliJ: How to disable condition hint during debug

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

The latest version of IntelliJ has introduced a new type of hint in debug mode. It looks like:

[image: IntelliJ condition hint]

Does anybody know how to disable it?

Also: does anybody know the term JetBrains uses for this feature? I can't look up the location of the setting in the setting search box without knowing what it's called!

Comment: Did you look at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#debugger? If something shows up in a new version, the release notes are a good place to start.

Comment: Please try to disable "Show values inline" in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views"

Comment: I looked at the release notes, (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2020.1+%28201.6668.121+build%29+Release+Notes) but not the "what's new" page (i didn't know about it). The trouble is that without knowing the name given to the feature its almost impossible to find what I'm looking for

Comment: @y.bedrov Thanks, but I disabled that a long time ago (for the exactly the same reasons as I want to remove this hint)

Comment: Do you have any custom plugins installed?

Comment: @y.bedrov, I've installed quite a few plugins from the Market Place (Setting | plugins), but nothing from outside the marketplace

Comment: Could you please try to temporarily disable custom plugins?

Comment: @y.bedrov, I've disabled every plugin, including the ones bundled with the IDE, but its not helped.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue on my machine. Is it possible to attach idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: @y.bedrov Sure can. Can I send it to you directly?

Comment: Yes. y.bedrov'at'gmail.com

Comment: @y.bedrov, on the subject of disabling the plugins, I've used the IDE to turn off *all* the plugins and restarted IntelliJ, but the logs are still telling me that some plug-ins are not working because their dependencies are not enabled. Is that normal?

Comment: Could you please provide new logs? Do you face the same issue with all plugins disabled?

Comment: Please try to run with default settings "File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings"

Comment: FYI -  I've also uninstalled and reinstalled IntelliJ, but that hasn't helped either

Comment: I've restored the default settings, but it didn't help.

Comment: I've finally found this feature. You may switch it off by unchecking the "Predict future condition values…" option in "Preferences / Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java"

Comment: @y.bedrov  Thanks so much. I would never have found that - even knowing its name I still wouldn't have guessed! If you want to submit that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may switch it off by unchecking the "Predict future condition values…" option in "Preferences / Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Java"